# Apex Charts custom XAxis tooltip label on mouseover

Tags: javascript, reactjs, apexcharts

[image]

I have this Apex chart's heatmap (https://apexcharts.com/) with days on x axis (01-31).

When the user mouseover i would like to add the shortened day of the week on tooltip, something like this:

[image]

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In `xaxis` change `tooltip` `formatter` to semething like this

```
xaxis: {
  tooltip: {
    formatter: (val, opts) => {
      let day = "FRI"; // your logic for getting day name
      return `${val}<br>${day}`;
    }
  }
},
```

https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/xaxis/#tooltipFormatter